# htaccess not working for page other than index

Tags: .htaccess

i want to hide variable from the url for a specific page like for domain/page.php?r=1 to domain/page/1

the htaccess is working for the index page but if i change the htaccess file for the specific page it stops working

### here is my code

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ index.php?r=$1
RewriteCond %{reset_pass} !-d
RewriteCond %{reset_pass}\.php -f
```

from this code i can print value of r if the page is index. but if i change it to other page it is not working

Comment: A `RewriteCond` has to _precede_ a `RewriteRule`.

Comment: What is `%{reset_pass}` meant to be?

Comment: And "it is not working" menas _what_ ?